# How to find biggest number out of 15 numbers?

Tags: vb.net

For a piece of computer science homework, I need to randomly generated 15 numbers, compare them all to each other and then output the biggest. But when I try to compare it to the largest variable it isnt 100% correct all the time. Can someone help me to get it 100% accuracy.

```vb
        Dim largest As Integer
        Dim random As New Random()
        Dim a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o As Integer

        Console.WriteLine("This program will generate 15 numbers and print the largest of them.")


        a = random.Next(0, 100)
        Console.WriteLine(a)
        b = random.Next(0, 100)
        Console.WriteLine(b)
        c = random.Next(0, 100)
        Console.WriteLine(c)
        d = random.Next(0, 100)
        Console.WriteLine(d)
        e = random.Next(0, 100)
        Console.WriteLine(e)
        f = random.Next(0, 100)
        Console.WriteLine(f)
        g = random.Next(0, 100)
        Console.WriteLine(g)
        h = random.Next(0, 100)
        Console.WriteLine(h)
        i = random.Next(0, 100)
        Console.WriteLine(i)
        j = random.Next(0, 100)
        Console.WriteLine(j)
        k = random.Next(0, 100)
        Console.WriteLine(k)
        l = random.Next(0, 100)
        Console.WriteLine(l)
        m = random.Next(0, 100)
        Console.WriteLine(m)
        n = random.Next(0, 100)
        Console.WriteLine(n)
        o = random.Next(0, 100)
        Console.WriteLine(o)

        If a > b Then
            largest = a
        ElseIf b > largest Then
            largest = b
        ElseIf c > largest Then
            largest = c
        ElseIf d > largest Then
            largest = d
        End If

        Console.WriteLine("The biggest number is " & largest)



        Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: `largest  = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o}.Max()` should do the trick. See [`IEnumerable.Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max).

Comment: Use a `List(Of Integer)` instead of single assignments, then use the same method that Ahmed suggested. Much cleaner. Or a `for each` loop where you store the highest value you find inside the list when parsing it.

Comment: Your teacher probably wants an algorithm comparing them all, though. You could make a function which compare 2 numbers and gives back the higher, and throw all your numbers in this function in a loop so you're left with the higher number if that's the case.

Comment: As laancelot menioned, your teacher may want an algorithm.  Your present code should work if You replace all the `ElseIf` statements with individual `If` statements.

Comment: @SpoonyCrab9131 Have you covered *arrays* yet? This would be a good time to use one to store the random numbers instead of having 15 separate variables.

Comment: make an array and call max on it, or loop over with for each, keep a var outside loop and inside of loop if var<num then var=num and when loop is done print result.

Comment: @SpoonyCrab9131 [Check](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z5fS4a) this out, hopefully you will learn a few things; remember there's more than a few ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler way to do what you're doing

```vb
Dim rand = New Random()
Dim numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 15).Select(Function(i) rand.Next(0, 100))
For Each number In numbers
    Console.WriteLine(number)
Next
Console.WriteLine($"The biggest number is {numbers.Max()}")
```

It uses an [IEnumerable(Of Integer)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.8) to hold the values, instead of individual variables. It first uses [Enumerable.Range()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.8) to create values 1 to 15 (these are not important) then converts them into random values with [Enumerable.Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8). It then uses [Enumerable.Max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.8) to get the maximum value.

This will also do the trick, however it doesn't use built in Enumerable functions, which might make it easier to pass it off as your own homework.

```vb
Dim rand = New Random()
Dim max = Integer.MinValue
For i = 1 To 15
    Dim number = rand.Next(0, 100)
    If max < number Then max = number ' this is probably what the teacher is looking for!
    Console.WriteLine(number)
Next
Console.WriteLine($"The biggest number is {max}")
```

Comment: The first one is too complicated for a beginner to understand, but it's a useful example for seasoned developers.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill TBH, **it depends** in my opinion. What I really think would be useful for the OP is to explain in details of what is wrong with their code, why it's not working, so they actually have an understanding of *why* it wasn't working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58382525/index-out-of-bounds-of-array[link] Check out this new question I have since I have improved the code.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ You learn to crawl and then walk before you run. Interfaces and generics are advanced topics for higher levels.