# Index out of bounds of array?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a program where it compares 15 randomly generated numbers to each other and outputs the largest one. I have done most of it but i get an error saying 'index was out of bounds of array'. I need the variable nextint to be the next index after currentint, hence the + 1 in order to compare them to each other. I will put the code below.

```vb
        Dim largest As Integer
        Dim random As New Random()
        Dim a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o As Integer
        Dim array1 As Array = New Integer() {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o}
        Dim index As Integer = array1.Length

        Console.WriteLine("This program will generate 15 numbers and print the largest of them.")



        For a = 0 To array1.Length - 1

            Dim currentint As Integer = array1(index)
            Dim nextint As Integer = array1(index + 1)

            currentint = random.Next(0, 100)
            nextint = random.Next(0, 100)

            Console.WriteLine(currentint)

            If currentint > nextint Then
                largest = currentint
            ElseIf nextint > currentint Then
                largest = nextint
            End If

        Next

        Console.WriteLine("The largest number is " & largest)

        Console.ReadLine()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You want to generate 15 random numbers and show the largest number of them?**

```
Dim random As New Random()
Dim listRandomNumbers As New List(Of Integer)

For nIndex As Integer = 1 To 15
    listRandomNumbers.Add(random.Next(0, 100))
Next

listRandomNumbers.Sort()

Dim smallestNumber As Integer = listRandomNumbers(0)
Dim largestNumber As Integer = listRandomNumbers(listRandomNumber.Count - 1)
```

---

The issue of your question is in the following line:

```
Dim nextint As Integer = array1(index + 1)
```

This is not possible in case `index` is `array1.Length - 1`. So you can skip the last round of the loop with the following code:

```
If index = array.Length - 1
    Continue For
End If
```

The new code of the `For` loop looks like this:

```
For a = 0 To array1.Length - 1

    If index = array.Length - 1
        Continue For
    End If

    Dim currentint As Integer = array1(index)
    Dim nextint As Integer = array1(index + 1)

    currentint = random.Next(0, 100)
    nextint = random.Next(0, 100)

    Console.WriteLine(currentint)

    If currentint > nextint Then
        largest = currentint
    ElseIf nextint > currentint Then
        largest = nextint
    End If
Next
```

You also overwrite the `nextint` and `currentint` with a random integer (`random.Next(0, 100)`). The init values of the variables are not used.

---

You can use a sort function instead of a `For` loop to get the largest number of the array. There is a simpler solution using [`Array.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort):

```
Dim a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o As Integer
Dim array1 As Array = New Integer() {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o}

Array.Sort(array1)

'largest and smallest number.
Dim largestNumber As Integer = array1(array1.Length - 1)
Dim smallestNumber As Integer = array1(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will add this to my code.

Comment: @SpoonyCrab9131 - I updated the answer. There is a simpler solution to get the largest number out of 15 random numbers.

Comment: I will use that then.

Comment: Are you instructed to do it this way and not to use array1,Min and array1.Max functions? Just wondering.